# default coding colors for visual studio c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am building an output generator that outputs code samples to html for a view.
Does anyone know where to find the default colors VS uses? i.e. for keywords, types, etc

Comment: Closing this question, which is asking what color hex codes are used in VS2015 so I can code them into a program that generates code on the fly? Last time I checked that IS PROGRAMMING. Find something more useless to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools->Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors

Comment: yeah, i looked there. These is no reference to the CSharp colors, just about everything else but that

Comment: @dinotom Hmm, sorry. Maybe it uses the C++ ones. You could look at the Visual Studio Color theme editor: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9e08e5d3-6eb4-4e73-a045-6ea2a5cbdabe